# set multi attributes at once without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, dom

There is a way to write this code in shorter way 
instead of

```
            var aTag = document.createElement('a');
            aTag.setAttribute('href', oUrl.toString());
            aTag.setAttribute('rel', "test");
            aTag.setAttribute('target', "_blank"),
            ...
```

I try with the following which is not working...is it possible?
I found in the net examples with Jquery but I don't want to use it now...

```
            var aTag = document.createElement('a'),
            .setAttribute('href', oUrl.toString()),
            .setAttribute('rel', "test"),
            .setAttribute('target', "_blank"),
            ...
```

Comment: you can create a function which will take a map as an input and add those attributes to element one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you could use a loop.

```
function setAttributes(el, attrs) {
  Object.keys(attrs).forEach(function (attr) {
    el.setAttribute(attr, attrs[attr]);
  });
}

var aTag = document.createElement('a');

setAttributes(aTag, {
  href: oUrl,
  rel: "test",
  target: "_blank"
});
```

Comment: Thank you Domenic! , I can use this, I saw your SO cv and we are facing some issue with chrome , is it possible to consult with you shortly ?maybe you can give some direction,if yes let me know how by email or ...Have a nice day and thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

You can create a for loop function

```
function setAttr(el, attrs) {
  for(var key in attrs) {
    el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
  }
}
```

And then to call it:

```
var aTag = document.createElement('a'),
setAttr(aTag, {
  "href": oUrl.toString(), 
  "rel": "test", 
  "target": "_blank"
});
```